# Hyperlinking to a specific sheet in the workbook

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, range, worksheet

I am trying to search for the sheet with the name of `TextBox1.Value` which is already created. Then find that same name on a sheet called "Employee List" and hyperlink that cell to the sheet with the same name.

It tries to link to "Name" inside the folder which I am working in. It doesn't even reach inside the workbook. Am I missing a parameter inside `.Hyperlinks`?

```
Dim findEmployee As Range
Dim foundEmployee As Range
Set findEmployee = Sheets("Employee List").Range("A:A")
Set foundEmployee = findEmployee.Find(TextBox1.Value)

With Worksheets("Employee List")
    .Hyperlinks.Add 
     Anchor:=.Range(foundEmployee.Address), _ Address:=Worksheets(TextBox1.Value).Range("A1"), _
     TextToDisplay:=TextBox1.Value
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this? When you record a macro, the subaddress is used rather than the address parameter, and it must be in the form of a string rather than range. if your sheet name has spaces you'll need to add single quotes to the string.

```
Sub x()

Dim findEmployee As Range
Dim foundEmployee As Range

Set findEmployee = Sheets("Employee List").Range("A:A")
Set foundEmployee = findEmployee.Find(TextBox1.Value)

If Not foundEmployee Is Nothing Then
    With Worksheets("Employee List")
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(foundEmployee.Address), _
                        Address:="", _
                        SubAddress:=Worksheets(TextBox1.Value).Name & "!A1", _
                        TextToDisplay:=TextBox1.Value
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: They all do have spaces. Around which string would I put these single quotations, the sheet name?

Comment: `"'" & Worksheets(TextBox1.Value).Name & "'!A1"`